# Django admin filter rows based on permissions

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

In the Django admin, I would like to display only certain rows of a model based on the user.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    text =          models.TextField(max_length=160)
    location =        models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

So, when a user logs into the admin site, and is part of the San Francisco `location`, they should only be able to see `Articles` with that location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is ModelAdmin's queryset:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ArticleAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.profile.location: # If the user has a location
            # change the queryset for this modeladmin
            qs = qs.filter(location=request.user.profile.location)
        return qs
```

This assumes the user is tied to a location via a profile model.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`has_add_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission), [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) and [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) with a [custom `ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) (in `admin.py`):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        # Nothing really to do here, but shown just to be thorough
        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).has_add_permission(request)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None:
            return obj.location == request.user.get_profile().location
        else:
            return super(ArticleAdmin, self).has_change_permission(request, obj=obj)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None:
            return obj.location == request.user.get_profile().location
        else:
            return super(ArticleAdmin, self).has_delete_permission(request, obj=obj)
admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```